# AJAX link causes div contents to be removed but new text is not inserted

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

*Using Rails 3.2.8*

Selecting the link produces the expected confirmation dialogue, "oh yeah?".

The expected result of selecting the OK button is that the text "the form goes here" in `<div id = "target">` should change to "the form\nsnookums".

The actual result is that the text "the form goes here" disappears as it should but nothing is placed in `<div id = "target"></div>`

The page code showing HTML5 doctype, jQuery files included by rails and AJAX link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="0ycwNRsr8kneUjB5/SFz+LD+bnhbQHXMJzgADbkv78g=" name="csrf-token" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/sessions/new" data-confirm="oh yeah?" data-remote="true">Hello world!</a>
      <div id="target">
        the form goes here
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The SessionsController,

`respond_with(@session)` will cause the variable `@session` to be passed through to app/views/sessions/new.js.erb

```
respond_to :html, :js
  def new
    @session = "snookums"
    respond_with(@session)
  end
```

The template: app/views/sessions/new.js.erb

```
var session_form = $('<%= j(render(:partial => "form")) -%>');
$('#target').html(session_form);
```

The form: app/views/sessions/_form.html.erb

Inspect Element with Firebug

```
GET http://localhost/sessions/new Response

var session_form = $('the form\nsnookums');
$('#target').html(session_form);
```

development.log

```
Started GET "/sessions/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-10 15:57:20 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#new as JS
the form "snookums"
  Rendered sessions/_form.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered sessions/new.js.erb (48.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 65ms (Views: 64.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Everything seems to be connected. Is the problem that there is something wrong with the response I am generating in new.js.erb? Is `$('#target').html(session_form);` equivalent to "replace the contents of the div 'target' with the text contained in 'session_form'?

BTW, FWIW I also tried it without the confirm - no difference.

Comment: what does your ajax code look like? Would help to see where you call `$('#target').html(session_form);` which does indeed say insert the new html in `id=target`

Comment: this is an invalid selector `$('the form\nsnookums');` ..not sure how this fits in. Again seeing more code will help

Comment: Thanks @Sean Vieira. All code, ex that provided by jQuery,is above. Briefly: 'Hello World!' link selected. Request goes to controller where '@session' is created by 'new' action. The 'new.js.erb' template generates javascript code to be executed on the div 'target'. The text 'the form\nsnookums' is assembled from  partial '_form' as argument to 'session_form = $( )'.  Firebug executes javascript, clearing div text... then fails to replace it with 'the form\nsnookums'. The selector is '$('#target')'. '$('the form\nsnookums')' is the text to be inserted by the 'html' method of the selector.

Comment: Sorry charlietfl, I got the attribution wrong; hope my coding is better!

Comment: you need to show more of the javascript code

Comment: The only javascript besides what is shown above (jQuery) is in query.js and query_ujs.js. I've posted them here: http://004150.com/login/articles/245?join=&topic=14tag=jQuery+files+http%3A%2F%2Fjqueryui.com%2F  FWIW -I followed this post to get to this point: http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2011/12/05/ajax-in-rails-3.html Thanks for looking..

Comment: where is the code for the button that is supposed to change the form?  If this is the actual output sent to page `var session_form = $('the form\nsnookums');` it is totally worthless. I think you are trying to add the full html for the complete form in that snippet which can work but the partial output is a mess

Comment: It's not a button, it's a link shown in HTML above: <a href="/sessions/new" data-confirm="oh yeah?" data-remote="true">Hello world!</a>. The form isn't a form, it's just a chunk of silly text. The javascript sent to the page is shown above under Inspect Element with Firebug which includes $('#target').html(session_form); The Request Header reads ' */*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript'. Same result if I omit 'respond_with' from controller. Thanks for your time charliefl.

Comment: if you hav a live link that can be inspected in browser console that would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

For ajax related problems it's a good habbit to use an error handler to see what returned.
For this i include this code block in all pages using ajax ;

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  error:function(x,e){
       if(x.status==0){
       alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
       }else if(x.status==404){
       alert('Requested URL not found.');
       }else if(x.status==500){
       alert('Internal Server Error.');
       }else if(e=='parsererror'){
       alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
       }else if(e=='timeout'){
       alert('Request Time out.');
       }else {
       alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
       }
  }
  });
```

Comment: I dropped this into application.js. No alert as yet.

Comment: can you supply us a url for testing ?

Comment: I don't have a way to deploy - my public server is still Rails 2.2.2. The main thing we have to work with here is the Firebug response.

Comment: I have sort of solved the problem. If I add some HTML tags around the text of app/views/sessions/_form.html.erb, the div is updated as expected. The Firebug Response looks like : "var session_form = $('<h1>the form<\/h1>\n<span>snookums<\/span>\n');
$('#target').html(session_form);". Interestingly, that was with "responds_to :js" (no ":html"). Sorry about any confusion I may have caused using "_form" for a file that doesn't contain a form yet. If anyone can explain how to replace text without the HTML tags, that might be a full fledged solution. Thanks for your interest.